# Apollo client with Vue and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, apollo-client

I have a rails app which is actually a clone of yts.mx. Now the idea was to have the front-end work in Vue.js, for which I created an independent Vue project inside the root directory of the existing rails app.

I have written GraphQl queries and tried using apollo client for communication with Vue but it gives me a dependency not found error with the path of the module Iv'e imported.

```
This dependency was not found:

* graphql/queries/movies/retrieveMovies.gql in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/MovieBlock.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save graphql/queries/movies/retrieveMovies.gql
```

Here's my `retrieveMovies.gql` file

```
query {
  movies{
    name
    release_date
  }
}
```

here's the script tag for the `MovieBlock.vue` Vue component

```
<script>
import  GET_MOVIES  from 'graphql/queries/movies/retrieveMovies.gql'
export default {
  name: 'MovieBlock',
 apollo: {
  movies: {
    query: GET_MOVIES,
    update: data => {
      debugger
    }
  }
},
  data () {
    return {
      movies: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's the Directory Structure of the project:

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: is the MovieBlock.vue and graphql directory inside the same directory at same level? If not, your path to gql file might be wrong.

Comment: Ive also tried giving the complete path of the file, and that doesn’t seen to work as well! `import  GET_MOVIES  from 'app/javascript/graphql/queries/movies/retrieveMovies.gql'`

Comment: When you begin your path without a `/` it is assumed as a relative path. That means then the path is calculated from wherever your vue component is and then `app/javasript....`

Comment: You might want to post your directory structure for better understanding .

Comment: Just updated the post!

Comment: yeah! looks like a path problem. Your gql files are *outside* your src directory for your frontend code. Your path might look something like this.

```../../../app/javascript...```

Comment: Great! got it, now the path is correct but I guess, since the GraphQL endpoints are established on the rails app on port:3000, getting the data to Vue on port:8081 seems to be an issue!